# Docker throws exception - Html2Pdf library

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I created an application using [htmlToPdf](https://github.com/wooio/htmltopdf-java)  and the application worked fine. but when I deployed it to my docker with the below pipeline.

```
FROM openjdk:8-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      libc6 \
      libx11-6 \
      libxext6 \
      libxrender1 \
      libstdc++6 \
      libssl1.0 \
      libfreetype6 \
      fontconfig \
   && apt-get clean \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I added these libraries because it needs them to run correctly. But still it's showing the same error showed in the documentation.

which is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so': Native library (tmp/io.woo.htmltopdf/wkhtmltox/0.12.5/libwkhtmltox.so) not found in resource path
```

I checked the /tmp folder of docker container it contains the required file as the exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you are struggling with html2pdf library.

But you are forgetting that this library usage [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) internally. so you can use that library. To use it in your java code you can use any wrapper.

Here is the link to that wrapper:  https://github.com/jhonnymertz/java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper

for example:

```
Pdf pdf = new Pdf();

pdf.addPageFromString("<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><h1>Müller</h1></html>");
pdf.addPageFromUrl("http://www.google.com");

// Add a Table of Contents
pdf.addToc();

// The `wkhtmltopdf` shell command accepts different types of options such as global, page, headers and footers, and toc. Please see `wkhtmltopdf -H` for a full explanation.
// All options are passed as array, for example:
pdf.addParam(new Param("--no-footer-line"), new Param("--header-html", "file:///header.html"));
pdf.addParam(new Param("--enable-javascript"));

// Add styling for Table of Contents
pdf.addTocParam(new Param("--xsl-style-sheet", "my_toc.xsl"));

// Save the PDF
pdf.saveAs("output.pdf");
```

Comment: It would be better, if you could provide a solution for the existing library.